# cancan: the difference between "manage" and the combination of "read, create, update and destroy"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

In trying to debug use of cancan i found that if use the following i can get past the accessdenied message:

```
  can :manage, Model
```

When i changed it to the following I am denied access:

```
  can :read, Model
  can :create, Model
  can :update, Model
  can :destroy, Model
```

What does manage include that the combination of read, create, update and destroy do not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define custom actions (When you define a user's abilities for a given model, you are not restricted to the 7 RESTful actions (create, update, destroy, etc.), you can create your own.) If you have manage all, you wold be able to access those custom actions too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know it worked on the actions. I thought it related strictly to the means of accessing data via the models. There are so many custom actions in the application the abilities model is probably going to triple in size and complexity. Darn!

Answer (score 23):

By default CanCan maps `:read`, `:create` etc. to the relevant controller actions e.g.:

```
def default_alias_actions
  {
    :read => [:index, :show],
    :create => [:new],
    :update => [:edit],
  }
end
```

But, of course you're not restricted to having just those actions in your controller, ultimately a controller action can have any name. By the same token you're not restricted to having just `:read, :create, :update, :detroy` in CanCan. You can alias any symbol to any controller action. Let us say you have an action on your controller called `do_cool_things`, you can then alias any symbol to that action to be used by CanCan e.g.:

```
alias_action :do_cool_things, :to => :coolify
```

You would then be able to do this:

```
can :coolify, Neighborhood
```

Which means the current user would have access to the `:do_cool_things` method of the `NeighborhoodsController`. However if you had used `:manage` you wouldn't need to define this separate action since `:manage` is a catch-all. So if you had done:

```
can :manage, Neighborhood
```

The current user would still have had access to the `:do_cool_things` method of the controller.

So, `:manage` lets you do anything, but `:read, :create, :update and :destroy` are only 4 of an infinite number of CanCan actions that you can define and map to any controller action you choose.

Comment: +1 for all the cool information provided. Thanks. Trying to figure out how to best design my ability model. If i post a related question i'll notify you.